# Tree Select With Check Boxes - Fixed Size of Input Bar

Tags: antd

Is there any way to make the input fixed or make tree appear as dropdown.
i tried this in component, at style but dit not do something.

```
render() {
     const tProps = {
      treeData,
      value: this.state.value,
      onChange: this.onChange,
      multiple: true,
      treeCheckable: true,
      showCheckedStrategy: SHOW_PARENT,
      searchPlaceholder: 'Please select',
      style: {
        width: 300,
        overflow:'auto',
        height:50
      },
    };
    return <TreeSelect {...tProps} />;   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i am using Tree instead of TreeSelect with popover like this.

```
<Popover
    visible={this.state.visible}
    title={<Checkbox onChange={this.checkAllKeys} checked={isAllChecked}>Select All</Checkbox>}
    onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
    trigger="click"
    content={
      <Tree
        checkable
        onExpand={this.onExpand} expandedKeys={this.state.expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={this.state.autoExpandParent}
        onCheck={this.onCheck} checkedKeys={this.state.checkedKeys}
        onSelect={this.onSelect} selectedKeys={this.state.selectedKeys}
      >
        {loop(treeData)}
      </Tree>
    }>
    <Button type="default">Click to check</Button>
  </Popover>
```